# how to fix memory error while using np.r_

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory

I have a list with `482000` entries. The structure of the array is like this:

```
X_docs = [array([0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]), 
array([0.60205999, 0.60205999, 0.47712125, ..., 0.  , 0.  ,0.])]
```

each array have `5000` entries. so in the end we have `482000 * 5000`.

Then I need to apply `np.r` over it like this:

```
np.r_[X_docs]
```

When it reaches this line it raises this error:

```
MemoryError
```

I dont know how to fix this? is there any limitation regarding the numpy thing?
I have 32 gig ram. I even tried to run it in AWS Amazon sagemaker(Free version). there it still raises error.

**Update 1**

This is the whole code before reaching the np part:

```
    corpus = load_corpus(args.input) 
n_vocab, docs = len(corpus['vocab']), 
corpus['docs'] corpus.clear() 
# save memory 
doc_keys = docs.keys() 
X_docs = [] 
for k in doc_keys:
 X_docs.append(vecnorm(doc2vec(docs[k], n_vocab), 'logmax1', 0))
 del docs[k] X_docs = np.r_[X_docs]
```

Comment: For float64 entries, you will need 482000 * 5000 * 8/1e9 ~= 20GB. You might want to first try lowering your precision to use float32 (set dtype=np.float32), see if that works.

Comment: @greeness it's worse, you need to account for the 8 byte pointer to each `np.ndarray` object plus the object overhead for each array.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. makes sense.

Comment: @greeness Thank you so much, I already tried to lowerto float 16 even but it did not help!!! Do you know which category of AWS amazon I can get in which it can run this? sorry for the off-topic question.

Comment: And if it only needs 20 GB whydo I face memory error at all? My system has 32 GB RAM!

Comment: You have to have space for all the initial arrays, plus space for the combined one.  The originals aren't overwritten or deleted, at least not during the concatenation phase.

Comment: @hpaulj Actually I checked the instances and variables before this line. this is the whole thing I have before `np` code:  `corpus = load_corpus(args.input)
    n_vocab, docs = len(corpus['vocab']), corpus['docs']
    corpus.clear() # save memory
    doc_keys = docs.keys()
    X_docs = []
    for k in doc_keys:
        X_docs.append(vecnorm(doc2vec(docs[k], n_vocab), 'logmax1', 0))
        del docs[k]
    X_docs = np.r_[X_docs]` as you see I have deleted variables before going to the np things.